# CodeIgniter rewrites URLs to lowercase. Can I bypass that?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to preserve the case of the URLS for certain controllers but codeigniter rewrites them to lowercase (due to htaccess I think).

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: i don't think URL is case-sensitive Todd. Any URL you type it will be converted into lowercase again.

Comment: I think this has been removed from CI3. In CI2 I think you'd have to extend the router class (_parse_routes())